# How to target a table based on ID, in order to iterate through its td-spans, and change spans color aswell as give out its value to console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to target with JQuery a Table id, and iterate through this specific Table td-spans, in order to change spans color to red and also give out to it's value to console.

I tried the following Code, but the style property didn't work, nor did `console.log()`

```js
$("span").each(function(index){
this.style.color="red"
console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Jquery</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table id="IDTable">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>Hallo Welt</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>Hallo1</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span>Hallo3</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would also like to Target this specific Table Spans, based on IDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

> $("#IDTable tr td span")

```js
$("#IDTable tr td span").each(function(index){
 this.style.color="red";
 console.log(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jquery</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<table id="IDTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Hallo Welt</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Hallo1</span>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Hallo3</span>
    </td>
  </tr>



</table>




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is missing a closing `);`

Try the following.

```
$("#IDTable span").each(function(index){
 this.style.color="red"
 console.log(this.innerHTML);
});
```

The difference is the last line, where i'm closing the `each` function.

Comment: Thank you, How can i also Target this specific Table based on ID?

Comment: @Roman check my update. You can specify multiple tags in the jquery selector

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#IDTable td span").each(function(index){
   this.style.color="red"
   console.log(this.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jquery</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<table id="IDTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Hallo Welt</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Hallo1</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span>Hallo3</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```